# Django group by and then serialize

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Given a simplified model `Student` with two fields: `name` and `grade`.
Currently I have a Viewset that uses a simple serializer and return all students.

It is possible that the same student has more than 1 grade and I would like to group all the grades of the same student, sort them and then use the serializer.

My desired output is not a list of Students but a list of lists where each inner list is a single student and his sorted grades.

I read about `annotated` but didn't manage to make it work...

(I am using django 1.8)

Comment: try using many=True inside your serializer

Comment: @A9eel I know this argument. I am having trouble building that complex queryset.

Comment: I think you need to restructure your models .. student model should have foreignkey(one-to-many) with grade

Comment: @AseelAshraf Correct. It was much easier after the restructure. Thanks.